# Plotting only forecasted value on Facebook Prophet model Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, graph, forecasting, facebook-prophet

When I plot with facebook prophet model by the following code:

```
number_of_days_in_future = 20
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=number_of_days_in_future, freq="D") 
weekend = future[future['ds'].dt.dayofweek < 5  ]
prediction = m.predict(weekend)
m.plot(prediction)
plt.title("Prediction of Value")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

It shows plotting from the beginning of historical data like below:
[image: Plotted]

It's difficult to understand the value from the graph as it spans large range for Y-axis.

But if I forecast only for few days. It's easier to understand the value from Y-axis like this:

[image]

**My questions are:**

1. Is there any way so that it doesn't span that large range? ( if we can ignore plotting the shadow part )
2. Is there any way just to plot the tail forecasted part? ( I don't want to plot whole historical data )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found a way from fbprophet repository to fulfill my requirements.

```
fig = m.plot(prediction)
ax = fig.gca()
# setting x limit. date range to plot
ax.set_xlim(pd.to_datetime(['2020-08-19', '2020-08-25'])) 
# we can ignore the shadow part by setting y limit
ax.set_ylim([26, 29])
```

The graph becomes clearer :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the shadow part, attribute to the 'uncertainty' plot parameter as 'False'.